# Is there any way to input the result got from the curl via fluentd?

Tags: alfresco, fluentd

We are seeking the most simple way for sending alfresco's audit log to elasticsearch.

I think using the alfresco supplying query and getting audit log would be most simple way.(since audit log data is hardly watchable on db)

And this query processes the effect measure as json type then I'd like to download the query direct using fluentd and send to elasticsearch.

I roughly understood that it would ouput at elasticsearc but I wonder whether I can download 'curl commend' using query direct at fluentd.

Otherwise, if you have other simple idea to get alfresco's audit log then kindly let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure weather I understood it fully or not but based on your last statement I am giving this answer.
To retrieve audit entries from alfresco repository you could directly use REST APIs of Alfresco which allows you to access them.[image]